# Using an Anonymous Class

Tags: java, class, anonymous

So I have a List

```
public static List<Position> chests = new ArrayList<Position>();
```

in my main class, but inside this main class, I have an Anonymous Class (a thread) which uses this list. For whatever reason, this thread cannot correctly read info from this list. Here's my other code for that Anonymous Class:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < ChestGrabber.getChests().size(); i++) {
            Position chest = (Position) ChestGrabber.getChests().get(i);
            if (player.getDistance(chest.x, chest.y,
                chest.z) <= 4.7F) {
                openChest((int) chest.x, (int) chest.y, (int) chest.z);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // chests.remove(chest);
            }
        }
    }
}).start();
```

I have tried to access the list a few different ways:

```
  ChestGrabber.getChests().size()
```

or

```
  getChests().size()
```

or

```
  chests.size()
```

.. and none of these work: they always return `0`, so the `for`-loop is skipped completely.

Am I overlooking something? I can't seem to get this to work.

Comment: How are you putting data in the list?

Comment: You List must be empty dude. Before the For loop the Sysout the List.size()

Comment: Yeah, has nothing to do with using an anonymous class.

Comment: @immibis It's adding because I have a debug feature that prints out the size, which every time I add an object to the list it increments.

Comment: @DevinK changes made in one thread are not guaranteed to be visible to other threads, except in specific circumstances. How are you putting data in the list? Also, post the implementation of `getChests`.

Comment: @Oliver Yeah that's the weird part. I did do that and this is what happens. [http://puu.sh/akH2R/29d0381354.png](here's the output) and [http://puu.sh/akH69/77b8b4538b.png](here's my code)

Comment: @immibis Here's how I [http://puu.sh/akH7X/2554fe5626.png](add chests) and here's how I [http://puu.sh/akHb5/82c42ba3cf.png](get the list)

Comment: So i guess that list is empty when you starting new thread.

Comment: @Antoniossss Yes, I guess so because my debug showed that the list had two objects in it before I started the thread. I've tried getters and I don't know what else I could try.

Comment: So the list is empty before you reach `start()` or not? Add line `System.out.println(ChestGrabber.getChests().size());` before `new Thread(new Runnable() {` line and see what happens
If you don't know what to try else, try putting anything in list first ;]

Comment: @DevinK : Surely there is a implementation problem with your ChestGrabber Class. Just paste the ChestGrabber code so people can help you.

Comment: @Antoniossss I did. [http://puu.sh/akH2R/29d0381354.png](here's](ouput) and [http://puu.sh/akH69/77b8b4538b.png](here's](code)

Comment: @Oliver [Here's my full class](http://pastebin.com/ynGLx1az). Ignore the clazz object, I was just trying that to see if it would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are invoking `chests.clear();` right after starting new thread (but that doesn't mean that thread is running after invoking `start()`) so the list is probably wiped out before new thread tries to read from it.

Answer (score 1):

Everything seems right. Try using an Iterator instead. And Since you are getting Something during the first call of ChestGRabber.getChest, save that in a list and the iterate over the same list in the for loop. It should have worked. Try what I told you, otherwise everything is right. Try Deleting your meta data of workspace and import project again(if ur using eclpise that is), try cleaning project. your code is correct

Comment: I don't think that using an Iterator would change anything. The size of the list (somehow) changes from outside the thread to inside (the first line of the run method. I could try it but I doubt it would change anything. I'll try the other things and see if that helps.